# Tag synonym pentest --> Penetration-Test

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We have 3 questions that use PenTest and likely more will follow.  What do you think of creating  a synonym for Pentest to automatically rename to Penetration-Test which seems to be the popular tag

Comment: makerofthings Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed.  Perhaps adding this answer will remove it from the community bulletin.

Comment: IIRC it has to be an upvoted answer (maybe accepted works as well, but I don't think self-accepted does). Anyway, upvoted will do it for sure.